# CFNetwork crashed on iOS 11.2.x

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-foundation, cfnetwork, ios11.2

My app encountered this crash in recent months.From the stacktrace as the following, I can‘t find any clue.This crash only happened on iOS 11.2.x and background thread. This bug almost happened only once on each user's device. I don't know if it is a bug from Apple.Can anybody give me some clues about this bug? Thanks a lot!

here is the stacktrace:
[image]

here is the device info for the bug:
[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @FawadMasud Absolutely not，I found that some of my friend's app also has the same crash.

Comment: Recently, I found the crash rate slows down.It also crashes on iOS 11.2.x and there are basically few crashes in the iOS 11.3 system. By the way, iOS 11.3 system accounts for half of our users.

Comment: From this [forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/99581) of apple development, the staff of Apple indirect that this may be a bug of CFNetwork itself.